# What is the role of 没 here?

Tags: meaning, usage

How can these sentences be translated into English? Are they questions or afirmative sentences?

1-洗没洗衣服

2-听没听音乐

3-复习没复习课文

Comment: They're questions, mean `have you done sth or not?`

Comment: Affirmative-negative question, cf。e。g。＂外国人实用汉语语法＂疑问句（三）正反疑问句（一）什么是正反疑问句。并列谓语肯定与否定形式表示疑问，要求作出肯定或否定的答复的疑问句是正反疑问句。它的基本格式是：１。主语＿＿＿谓语＿＿＿＂不（没）＂＿＿＿谓语＿＿＿（宾语）？例如：方向＿＿＿对＿＿＿不＿＿＿对？效果＿＿＿好＿＿＿不＿＿＿好？他＿＿＿是＿＿＿不＿＿＿是＿＿＿内科大夫？你＿＿＿换＿＿＿不＿＿＿换＿＿＿病间？天上＿＿＿有＿＿＿没＿＿＿有＿＿＿星星？他＿＿＿参加＿＿＿没＿＿＿参加＿＿＿联欢会？
Q has examples w/o  subject (无主句）1-洗没洗衣服：洗＿＿＿没＿＿＿衣服？

2-听没听音乐：听＿＿＿没＿＿＿听＿＿＿音乐？

3-复习没复习课文：复习＿＿＿没＿＿＿复习＿＿＿课文？
２。(二)（２nd pattern）主语＿＿＿谓语＿＿＿宾语＿＿＿＂不（没）＂＿＿＿谓语？

Answer (score 3):

They're all questions.

1-洗没洗衣服 = Have you washed the clothes or not?

2-听没听音乐 = Have you listened to music or not?

3-复习没复习课文 = Have you revised the text or not?

All three sentences have the same structure. If you break the first one apart, you get this:

洗 = wash(ed)

没洗 = not wash(ed)

衣服 = clothes

Comment: 复习： brush up brush up on go over review

Comment: @user6065 They all have similar meanings :)

Comment: revise： 修订； 改变； 修正；［美国英语］[主英国英语]复习

Comment: I also use 复习 or 温习 as in "revising for an exam".

Answer (score 1):

They are the same as the verb + 不 + verb structure, but negating a the past action:

洗不洗 - do you wash or not?
洗没洗 - did you wash or not?

听不听 - do you listen or not?
听没听 - did you listen or not?